# docker build step Jenkins plugin - configured dockerFolder .....does not exist

Tags: jenkins-plugins

My jenkins job is trying to build an image. 
It tells me that the docker folder in the Jenkins workspace does not exist which is true.
The Dockerfile is at the same level as the pom.xml so is not under a folder called docker.
My questions are is there any documentation for this plugin?
Do I need to put the Dockerfile in a directory called docker?
Can I tell the plugin step where to look for the Dockerfile?
Regards,John

Comment: So I added a docker folder and put the Dockerfile in that and now it runs within the Jenkins plugin. But it also means the copy steps are incorrect. They can be fixed but is there a way of defining where the Dockerfile is when using the plugin?

Comment: Actually I am not sure that can be fixed so is there a way of defining where the Dockerfile is in the plugin build step?